# Asp.net >>Error >> could not copy the file "obj\Debug\[filename.dll]"because it was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, build

the problem is when i run any any asp.net project , it give me this error

> could not copy the file "obj\Debug[filename.dll]"because it was not
>   found.

i really don't know what to do, and i don't want to reinstall as you all know visual studio is painstakingly slow when it comes to install or uninstall it,
am using Visual studio 2015

btw, some thing also happens, when the file is being built a cmd window opens and close immediately and it happens automatically, i think this is what it cause the problem.

Edit :
i found the answer , simply i reset every thing to default , and when i create a new project i set it to the default directory , i don't know if its the real solution but it worked .

Comment: Clear the temp file and asp.net temp folders, then restart the computer that might fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the target .NET Framework to 4.6.1.

See [Changing the Target .NET Framework Version or Profile for an Existing Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_1) for instructions on how to do this.